# Avoid impact to performance, when designing activity with more than 80 views

Tags: android

I'm new to android. I'm creating an application, which should handle more than 200 settings, mostly Boolean. Settings can be grouped by they type, there are 5 groups. I assume, that users won't like to configure and save each group separately,but would like to configure all the settings and by pressing save -> save all of them at one time, so scenario with having 5 different activities for each setting group doesn't suite.

What I've tried to do, is set up a TabHost, with separate tab for each group. After I've got "more than 80 views" warning, I've split up my layout, and now each group has own layout.xml;

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSetting1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strSetting1" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cbSetting2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/strSetting2" />
    </TableRow>

...
</TableLayout>
```

And I'm inflating those views onCreate:

```
View setting1View= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.group1_layout, null);
group1Tab.addView(view);
```

With this steps done, I'm avoiding "more than 80 views warning", but won't have it impact on performance, when all views are inflated -> activity will have more than 80 views in total?

Next question: should I get references to all CheckBoxes on my views onCreate:

```
CheckBox setting1 = (CheckBox)setting1View.findViewById(R.id.cbSetting1);
```

or should reference them on my saving button press, like:

```
onSaveClick{
      Boolean setting1Value = ((CheckBox)setting1View.findViewById(R.id.cbSetting1)).value
}
```

or in some other way, to have as little performance impact as possible?

Is there any "good pattern", for designing apps with a lot of views?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I know, that "best practice" questions are not recommended on StackOverflow, but I've tried to ask as defined questions as possible, and, hopefully, my post is showing at least my researching effort on the issue.

**Update**
My fault not mentioning it earlier - those settings are stored remotely, and are accessed using HTTP requests (using Web-api). Does suggestions about Preference activities/fragments and ListViews fit in this case?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fragments? Fragment is a better option in your case. It provides scalability and you also won't have to hard code everything. check this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html

Comment: Yes, I'm looking forward to them, but I'm a newby in android. Will I be able to Save all the settings at one time from all the fragments?

Comment: Also, Fragmets require pretty high minimum API level, it could be the problem..

Comment: Each fragment has its own class and its very easy to handle content of fragment in the class. In this way, you can easily save values for settings

Comment: Yes API level can be the issue but if your application is not supporting lower APIs it is best possible solution

Comment: Fragments are supported pretty low you just need the support library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way you have described your application, it seems like you have many similar views. I would recommend using a `ListView` in each of your tabs. `ListView`s very efficiently handle tons of views.

You will need to write a custom adapter for you `ListView`s, but you can do this cleverly in a way that doesn't call `findViewById()` all the time ([using the `ViewHolder` pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)).

It is hard to give specific advice because you have not described exactly what these settings items will contain, but this general idea works well when you have long lists of (event potentially slightly different) views. This pattern would work if you want to have a lot of flexibility over you layout. [If you want some standard settings behavior, check out `PreferenceFragment`s](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html), or check out Android's [settings developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html).

Comment: Yes, it is, I'm having very much similarity (as I've mentioned in @AabidMulani answer comment, 90% of my settings are Boolean, so I mostly will use CheckBoxes). Will I be able to achieve "Saving all settings at one time" using your suggested pattern?

Comment: My solution would easily allow that, if you really think that is better than changing settings as the user changes an option. However, most android settings menus change a setting immediately as the user selects to change the setting.

Comment: I'm assuming so, because, actually, I have winforms application prototype, which I'm migrating to android, and that app has "save all at once" pattern. I suppose, users, who are familiar with windows app, would expect the same behaviour from android one.

Comment: As much as possible, try to avoid porting behavior from other platforms. Design for what makes sense to Android users. Not to say that a "Save" button isn't a good idea. You could still have it, but do nothing ;)

Comment: That's why I've opened this discussion. I'm new to android, and I don't want to make mistakes at design time, which will be costly to refactor. Thank you!

Comment: Mistakes are unavoidable as a beginner to Android. Good luck!

Comment: If I understood everything correctly, preferences does not suit for me. I've ended with creating TabHost, where each tab is separate fragment, handling group of settings. Also, I've removed Save button and refused using "save all at once".

Answer (score 1):

If its just boolean settings [i.e. Checkbox].
Then I would prefer trying [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), its just like another activity but preferably used for settings functionality. Also there is an easy way to group your settings element, try [PreferenceCategory](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceCategory.html) for grouping.

A small tutorial is available [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/preference/prefernces-and-preferenceactivity-example/). 
CheckBoxPreference is what you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: They are mostly, ~90% Boolean settings -> CheckBoxes, but there are some String as well.

Comment: Yes you can handle strings also... Look for EditTextPreference.

Comment: I'm not an android-lightning, to implement suggested topic, which I'm not familiar with, in less than hour :) I'll definately accept an answer, when I'll be able to check if it's working. Thank you!